# Draytek Vigor 5510 pro blocking attachments un-necessarily

Tags: security, firewall, url, vigor

I have installed Draytek vigor pro 5510 which I may say is one of the hardest ones on the planet to configure but I have now gained success with it in blocking URL(s) successfully but when I implement the keyword ‘download’ or some similar words then it also blocks the downloading of the attachments from hotmail un-necessarily but is fine with yahoo mail and Gmail. I have tried to sort out this problem by completely putting hotmail under exception but that never works too.

Secondly, the blocked URL(s), when accessed does not show the admin message because it gets blocked or conflicted by Kaspersky Antivirus on the client machines and I can’t figure it out to weak which option, is it either in firewall itself or the Kaspersky Anti Virus on the client machines?

Answer (score 1):

You r right its the Kaspersky which is blocking the messages. if you will "disable" Web and banner protection, your internet explorer will start showing admin messages by your router but still can't find any other way to keep the admin messages displaying with these antivirus options "enable" mentioned above.